# JQuery pick which fields to serialize

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, serialization

I have a form in ASP.NET MVC which contains a `DropDownList` where I need to serialize the text value of the currently selected option in the list, not the value of that option. Then, I need to serialize a `TextArea` and send those both in the same query string. I have tried to select my `DropDownList` text using this JQuery statement:

```
var _dropDown = $('#ConfigList option:selected').text().serialize();
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text(...).serialize is not a function
```

**My Question**

How do I get the text value of my dropdownlist and my textarea, and serialize them together? They are both in the same input field which I am passing in to my JQuery function that serializes them.

Comment: don't use `.text()`. that turns whatever the `$()` selector turned into a plain string, it WON'T be html anymore, just the text contents of whatever html was matched. `$('#config').serialize()`

Comment: Use a hidden input that has its value updated to the `.text()` of the select list whenever it changes. Then it's just `$("#my_textarea, #my_hidden").serialize()`;

Comment: @squint How do I create a hidden input for a DropDownList? I'm not using a DropDownListFor.

Comment: @MarcB The issue is that when I serialize my dropdownlist I get the value, not the text of actual option. I need the text of the option (what shows in the dropdownlist)

Comment: so for `<option value="foo">bar</option>` you want `bar`, not `foo`? why not make that the value as well, then?

Comment: @MarcB Yes that's what I want. I don't want to make that the value because the values are then placed into a textarea for the user to edit. I know it's not the most efficient way of doing it, but it's a corporate tool and my boss told me to do it this way so I have no choice.

Comment: I don't know anything about asp.net. I'm just saying that if you create a plain old `<input type="hidden">` with the proper ID and NAME attributes, then put a `change` handler on the select to update it when the select changes, you can use that hidden input to serialize the value that was set. *(I assume `DropDownList` creates an element that responds to `change` events.)*

Comment: then .text() is acceptable, but you can't serialize that. capture all of the text values, stuff them into an array, and serialize that instead.

Comment: @MarcB Can you show me how to capture the text value for a form which I have passed in to an external JQuery function? I have a JavaScript function on my view which then passes in the form to the external JQuery function, but I don't know enough JQuery to know how to then access that field in the form.

Comment: `$('#whatever ...').each(function(...) { textarray.push(this.text()); };`, in ugly pseudo-ish code, then you take `textarray` and serialize it.

Comment: @MarcB Ok, but how do I actually select the dropdownlist from the form I pass in? My list is called `ConfigList`

Comment: exactly what you have in your code above...

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Bind a handler to update the hidden input when the select changes
$("select").on("change", function() {
  $("#my_hidden").val(this[this.selectedIndex].text);
}).change();

// serialize it
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var res = $("#my_textarea, #my_hidden").serializeArray();

  $("pre").text(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="my_hidden" name=my_hidden type="hidden">

<select>
  <option value="FOO_VALUE">foo
  <option value="BAR_VALUE">bar
</select>

<br><textarea id="my_textarea" name=my_textarea>some content</textarea>

<br><button>serialize</button>

<pre></pre>
```

Comment: How do I select `my_textarea` and `my_hidden` in a form which I have passed in to an external JQuery function?

Comment: You're passing the form itself? Then you should just be able to do a DOM selection from that form. `$(my_form).find("#my_textarea")` If the form is in the page, then you'd be able to do it just like I've shown in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

to serialize all **form**  values you will have to use the **ID** of the form, it will automatically serialize all field values to serialized form. Also if you will use **.text()**, it will remove all html tags if any, so make sure before adding **.text()** to serilize.

Now for the dropdown if you really dont need the value tag anywhere den why are you putting that. remove it and then it will automatically get the text value which is visible in the dropdown.

```
var serialized = $("#form_name").serialize();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do not want. I know how to serialize all the fields in a form, I am trying to select individual fields and text values of lists.

Comment: Maybe he needs the value there for other purposes.